# Use residue calculus to evaluate an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, residue-calculus

Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue absolutely continuous measure on $\mathcal{R}$ defined by the density

\begin{equation}
d \mu = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \sqrt{4-t^2}dt, -2 \leq t\leq 2.
\end{equation}

How can I use the residue calculus to evaluate the singular integral

\begin{equation}\int_{\mathcal{R}}{\frac{1}{z-t}}d\mu(t)\end{equation}
for every $z=x+iy \in \mathcal{C}, y>0.$?

I tried to solve it by finding a closed positively oriented contour, I did choose the contour to be the upper half of a circle with radius R. But I did not know how to handle with the density $\mu$. Note that the integral of the density is one ($\mu =1$), but I do not know if this helps.

Comment: What work have you done on it?  If you've worked on the integral, please include your workings in an edit to your post.  This is only a problem-statement question, and it's pretty much a "copy and paste" of work you've been assigned to do.  So show us some of your work, please.  If you haven't worked on it, then it's also a "do my work for me" expectation.

Comment: You've received a couple of comments on other posts which are similar to my comment above. But it seems you continue on expecting others to do your work for you. Not good.

Comment: I did include me trial to solve it, but still on hold!

Comment: You've got three reopen votes (including my reopen vote); two more and your question will be opened again.